# Is there a universal way to check NULL in ResultSet?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

In Java, is there a universal way to check NULL in a ResultSet (java.sql.ResultSet)?

The ResultSet interface does not have a direct method to check NULL. The closest thing is the wasNull() method. So, I have come up with this idea:

```
ResultSet rs;    //the ResultSet object
Object theValue;
boolean isValueNull;

theValue = rs.getObject("MY_COLUMN");
isValueNull = rs.wasNull();
```

After executing the code, isValueNull should indicate whether the value is NULL.

But, there is a question: Does rs.getObject(...) work for all columns? By contrast, if you call rs.getBigDecimal(...) on a string column, an exception may occur. I guess that rs.getObject(...) works for all columns, but I am not sure.

Comment: Doesn't `if(theValue==null)` do what you are looking for?

Comment: As CannedMoose suggests, you only really need to call `wasNull()` when using the primitive getters for boolean, short, int and long. When using `getObject`, you can just check the returned value for `null`.

Comment: Maybe, but checking null for the return value of getObject() still requires getObject() works for all columns, so the question still remains. Besides, wasNull() is more convenient. Otherwise, you have to write a if statement or something like isValueNull = (theValue == null);

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

The universal way to check if last value from resultSet was null is to check rs.wasNull();

Yes, wasNull indicates whether the value was NULL.

Yes, getObject works on all columns.

Comment: Yes, the API documentation states explicitly that wasNull indicates whether the value was NULL. But, I don't find anything in the documentation that states explicitly that getObject works on all columns. I guess it does, but I'm not very sure.

Comment: @zhoudu Nothing in the documentation of `getObject` suggests there are exceptions for certain types (except maybe UDTs), as such you can take it to mean it will work for all types of columns. If you still have doubts, you can also read the entire [JDBC specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html) (e.g appendix B.3 lists the standard mapping of JDBC/SQL types to Java types for `getObject`).